# Button inside textview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, textview

After a long search on the web, I’m still struggling with this problem.

I’m developing an app for iOS in swift and I need to put a button inside a textview (not a textfield).
The button should be always in the right bottom corner of the textview, and it doesn’t have to move when the textview expands when the user types his text.
Of course, the text shouldn’t go over the button.

I found several solutions for this, but related to the textfield. 
The same approach doesn’t seems to work for me.

Can someone help?

Comment: The trickest thing will be to prevent that the text overlaps the button. Maybe you should take a look at `exclusionPath`s, like here: https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/280-flowing-text-around-images-with-exclusion-paths

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your own container that holds both components.

```
Main View
 - > TextView     
 - > Button
```

Add required constraints. Something along the lines of:

```
**button**: height constraint; bottom constraint to container.
**TextView** top + bottom constraint to container
**Main View** height constraint (and adjust it based on button action and text)
```